# Unnecessary use of variables

Tags: android, random

I am a little confused over why people recommend you use:

```
long rantime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
Random random = new Random(rantime);
```

when we could use:

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Will the single line method fail? And if not, isn't it more efficient since you don't create a variable unnecessarily?

Is it best practice to avoid using additional variables where possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people consider this:

```
long rantime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
Random random = new Random(rantime);
```

to be more readable than this:

```
Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Given how complex Android projects can grow to be, I *strongly* suggest that you value readability over trivial optimizations involving the number of local variables you use in your program. The compiler will optimize these things most of the time anyway.

Comment: Exactly. On top of this, the compiler normally is smart enough to know that the two line code is functionally the same as the one line and will optimize it so its not creating variables unnecessarily

Comment: Yup, just updated my answer :)

Comment: Most people is not all people. I prefer the shorter version, I find it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

### Random and it's seed

This isn't even necessary, the default constructor of `Random` already uses the System Time as a seed. So just use `Random random = new Random();`

[see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#Random%28%29)

Comment: Sorry I am not giving you the tick on this one although arguably you went one better than the other answer. Here's a "answer is useful" up for you. Thanks.